# Should I include a job reference from my current employer who has given leave of absence in order to find a new job?

Tags: references, germany, leave-of-absence

My current employer is going to end my employment soon due to a mistake-you-only-make-once that I made. I'm currently given leave of absence in order to find a new job. I already received a job reference (German "Arbeitszeugnis"). However, it carries the future date of the day on which my employment will officially end.

How do I handle this in my current job applications? Should I include the reference and explain in the cover letter why it's dated in the future? Or should I leave it away, effectively leaving out the fact that I'm having to leave my current job soon?

Comment: When applying for jobs I'm sure people will know you intend to leave your job soon.

Comment: Right. That was badly worded. I rewrote the question accordingly.

Comment: I could (and probably would) leave earlier, yes.

Comment: Does the reference letter give you good grades?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're making a bigger problem of this than it has to be. The situation you're in actually happens quite often. Either an employer needs to let you go and gives you time, or you tell the employer you want to leave at date x.

Just include the reference letter, it's not weird that it has a date. It might give you a little less leverage on the 'but my current company will offer x if I stay' side but I believe that's the only downside here.

Just be honest with why you're leaving and what you're looking for now. Nobody will create a fuzz about the date in the letter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommand against lying about the fact you have to go in general. Telling the truth about a mistake you did, and why you are here, will put you in sane ground and confidence relationship with any potential recruiter.

Since you have a recommandation letter, this is further argument not to. The fact it is dated in the future is easily understandable, and having a recommandation letter is always good to make an application serious and professional.